# Question based on profit, loss and C.P/S.P

Tags: algebra-precalculus

An honest milkman mixes 20% by volume of Bisleri to his milk and then sells the whole at the cost price of milk. If Bisleri costs 20% of the cost price of milk, what is the net profit percentage?

What I did:-

Initial volume= 100L Initial selling price= Rs100
Volume after adding Bisleri= 120L selling price= Rs 120
Profit= $120-100/100*100=20$%
But the correct answer is $15.38$%
What is wrong in my way of approaching this question? Also, any new ideas are always welcome

Comment: Hint: The costs for the Bisleri is $ 20 \ [l]\cdot 0.2\cdot p_m [u/l] $. And the cost for the milk is $100 \ [l] \cdot p_m [u/l]$, where $p_m$ is the price of milk( monetary unit per liter $[u/l]$).

Comment: Didn't get it. What is pm and u/l?

Comment: $p_m$ denote the price per liter for the milk. And the "unit" of it is monetary unit (u) per liter (l). You don´t really need them to get the right result.They can be cancelled. But I want to make clear my thoughts behind the expression for the costs.

Comment: Didn't understand it yet @callculus The way you have written it is quite confusing

Comment: In your words: Calculating the costs: **I assume that the milk costs** $RS100/L$  The amount of Bisleri is $ 20 L$ . The amount of milk is still $100L$. The costs of the Bilserii per liter is  $0.2\cdot RS100/L$. And the costs of the milk per liter is $RS100/L$. Thus the total costs are $20L\cdot 0.2\cdot RS100/L+100L\cdot RS 100/L$

Comment: What is RS? @callculus

Comment: It´s the currency sign for rupees. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rupee